# Is there a way to add CSS style to flextable (for rendering in html format in RStudio/browser)?

Tags: r, flextable

Default behaviour of many browsers and also RStudio html viewer is white-space:normal which collapses the sequences of white space in tables. So following code:

```
library(flextable)
aaa<-data.frame()
aaa[1,1]<-"aaa"
aaa[2,1]<-"     a     aaa"
ft <- flextable(aaa)
ft <- align_text_col(ft, align = "left")
ft <- align_nottext_col(ft, align = "left")
ft <- border(ft, border= fp_border(color = "black") )
ft
```

table where spaces before "a" are removed and spaces after "a" are shrinked to one space. This can be avoided by adding CSS style

```
white-space:pre
```

to the resulting html. This can be achived in RShiny app, but I did not fidn a way how to do that in RStudio. Any clues?
Thanks in advance.

Tomas

Comment: the behavior you want is the expected one, I fix it in the package (on github for now)

Comment: @dav Thats solved it, thank you!